# Error al importar una base de datos mysql en phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

### -- Database: `i8187316_wp1`

---

### --
-- Table structure for table `wp_actionscheduler_actions`

CREATE TABLE `wp_actionscheduler_actions` (
`action_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`hook` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
`status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
`scheduled_date_gmt` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`scheduled_date_local` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`args` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`schedule` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci,
`group_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`attempts` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`last_attempt_gmt` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`last_attempt_local` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`claim_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`extended_args` varchar(8000) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAUL[...]
MySQL said: Documentation
#1046 - No database selected

Comment: en el phpmyadmin tienes que crear la base de datos, mismo nombre, despues el comando use name_database; y despues exportas la bd, tienes que tenerla seleccionada

Comment: Eso en el nuevo servidor al importar? O en el antiguo servidor al momento de exportar?

Comment: por ejemeplo tengo el HOST 1 Y EL HOST 2, el HOST 2, tiene la base de datos completa, se exporta la query y tienes el archivo .sql, ahora en el HOST 1 , donde no hay nada, creas la bd con el nombre i8187316_wp1, y luego use i8187316_wp1; Y AHI RECIEN EXPORTAS O COPIAS LA QUERY

Comment: Mil gracias, lo logré!

Comment: 1. Pon en el título de la pregunta _qué error dio_. 2. Dale formato la pregunta: tal cual como está es "pesada" de leer. 3. No olvides aceptar la respuesta que te fue útil.

Answer (score 0):

por ejemeplo tengo el `HOST 1` Y `EL HOST 2`, el `HOST 2`, tiene la base de datos completa, se exporta `la query` y tienes el archivo `.sql`, ahora en el `HOST 1` , donde no hay nada, `creas la bd con el nombre i8187316_wp1`, y luego `use i8187316_wp1;` Y AHI RECIEN EXPORTAS O COPIAS LA QUERY